# PHP adding new .dll makes Apache server unable to start

Tags: php, configuration, dllimport, libssh2

I am trying to add an extension to my PHP.  I have the file - libssh2.dll - in the appropriate directory (as listed in my php.ini file) and made sure the extension=libssh2.dll.  I also copied the .dll file to system and system32 folders as other threads have suggested.  When I try to start my Apache server I get the following windows error:

Apache HTTP Server has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry for the inconvenience.

and Apache Monitor error:

The requested operation has failed!

I check the log to see this:

[Tue Jul 26 16:43:06 2011] [warn] pid file C:/Program Files/Apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?

I have tried to go in this direction but am completely stumped at this point.  Hoping someone out there can help me and so I can figure out what's wrong.  Thanks in advance guys!

Cheers

Comment: See: http://serverfault.com/questions/77747/apache-unclean-shutdown-of-previous-apache-run

Comment: @Dor that thread addresses a different issue: it tells me to simply comment out "extensions", but the thing is I need to use libssh2.dll, so I can't really comment it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is telling you that you need to remove just the previous pid file. Each time that you run apache a http.pid file is created in apache's bin folder. It contains the apache pid.

Comment: The "unclean shutdown" message is a symptom, not the problem.

Comment: Well, the problem is that the dll that he is trying to set as extension is probably not compatible. For example, i have installed today microsoft sql server extension and if you dont install the right one of all the dlls (there are like 10) it doesnt work. It needs to use the same API version and compiled in VC6 or VC9.

Comment: @Hamboy75 the deleting of the http.pid did not work for me; I receive the same error

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by upgrading to 5.3.  Somehow with the same settings it automagically worked.  Closing the issue now.